# How to use iterable in StepVerifier in Spring Reactive testing

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-reactive

I have written a test method for creation of `Flux` object.

**Test Method:**

```
@Test
public void testCreateFlux() {
    Flux<String> fruitFlux = Flux
            .just("A", "B", "C", "D");

    StepVerifier.create(fruitFlux)
            .expectNext("A")
            .expectNext("B")
            .expectNext("C")
            .expectNext("D")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

My question is there any way I can simplify my test method without using multiple `expectNext()`
statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expectNext` is overloaded to accept multiple types.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/3.1.2.RELEASE/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.Step.html

https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/3.1.2.RELEASE/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.Step.html#expectNext-T-T-T-T-T-T-

```
StepVerifier.Step<T> expectNext(T t1,
                                T t2,
                                T t3,
                                T t4,
                                T t5,
                                T t6)
```

There's methods that accept less, and one that accepts varargs.

It can also accept an `interable` via the `expectNextSequence` method

https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/3.1.2.RELEASE/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.Step.html#expectNextSequence-java.lang.Iterable-